# Читалка книгу в Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Делаю приложение библиотеку, внутри детальной страницы есть прочитать книгу, вот , в Flutter-е есть какой нибудь плагин который делает из pdf читалку книгу или как нибудь можно сделать чтобы удобно было читать через приложение?

Answer (score 1):

[Их много](https://pub.dev/packages?q=pdf), в основном все используют нативную часть для отображения. Выбирайте сами, какой для вас будет удобнее.

Comment: Дело в том что в pdf-е не удобно читать книгку ,  хочу именно какой нибудь плагин или читалку добавить в приложении

Comment: @АкбарСулаймонов, я не так выразился. Они будут отображаться у вас в приложении, но для рендеренга будут использовать нативный код. По этому можете делать собственную читалку на основе этих плагинов. Так-как неизвестно как они работают, необходимо протестировать и выбрать подходящие для вас.

Comment: спасибо за ответь